# Leaflet remove old layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, leaflet

If I search for different locations, the map continues to show the old layers. How can I sort out it?

Please find below the code:

```
        $("#searchBtn").click(function() {

            query = $("#searchInput").val();
            if (query) {

                draw_counties(query, map);
            }

        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Polp026/17ux3gpk/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
Now it works!

```
        $("#searchBtn").click(function() {
            query = $("#searchInput").val();
            if (query) {
            map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                map.removeLayer(layer);
                });   
                draw_counties(query, map);
                basemap.addTo(map);
            }    
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Polp026/17ux3gpk/32/